# Targeting nested lists

Tags: html, css

Wanting to do a nested list. Where I can make the outer-list displayed as inline-block and the inner list and as a block. I must be targetting the classes of each list wrong because I'm not able to apply these preferences? thanks :)

```css
.days ul li {
  display: inline-block
}

.points ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="days">
    <h2>Title</h2>

    <ul class="points">
      <li>Point 1</li>
      <li>Point 2</li>
  </li>
  </ul>
</ul
```

Comment: The second UL should be inside the LI. But, it seems like you are looking for a dd dl dt. If you want the title to be on the left and the points on the right, you might want to look at float.

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Only `li` can be a direct descendant of `ul`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector in your CSS is wrong. You're selecting the ul "inside" element with .days and .points class. What you need is a li inside your ul element, in this case .days and .points.

Another problem is your html synthax. Only li can be ul descendant, so you need to put the second ul inside the li.

```css
.days li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}

.points li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="days">
  <li>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul class="points">
      <li>Point 1</li>
      <li>Point 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <ul class="points">
      <li>Point 1</li>
      <li>Point 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```